# Run Maven build with manually downloaded dependencies

Tags: java, maven, adal4j

Apologies if this is an easy fix, I'm new to Java and Maven and am struggling a little with getting it working.

I'm trying to implement the [ADAL4J sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java) on my work machine. Unfortunately, because of various security reasons, my work machine does not have access to the Maven repository and is unable to be temporarily hooked up to download and required packages.

I've had the sample up and running on my personal machine, generated a list of dependencies through Maven and manually downloaded them onto my work machine (the jar files), but this is where I get stuck.

How do I configure the Maven build process to use local jar files instead of trying to download them from the Maven remote repo?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, any solution is to be deployed with VSTS, which also does not have access to the Maven repository, so any way of referencing the dependencies independent of the Maven repository must be able to be bundled up with the build process (it currently generates a WAR file) and deployed to a remote Tomcat server.

Comment: You can `mvn install` them to your local repo....

Answer (score 2):

Just install your jars manually to your local repository:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

> **Guide to installing 3rd party JARs**
>
> Although rarely, but sometimes you will have 3rd party JARs that you
>   need to put in your local repository for use in your builds, since
>   they don't exist in any public repository like Maven Central. The JARs
>   must be placed in the local repository in the correct place in order
>   for it to be correctly picked up by Apache Maven. To make this easier,
>   and less error prone, we have provide a goal in the
>   maven-install-plugin which should make this relatively painless. To
>   install a JAR in the local repository use the following command:
>
> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
>     -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
> ```
>
> If there's a pom-file as well, you can install it with the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
> ```
>
> With version 2.5 of the maven-install-plugin it gets even better. If
>   the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a
>   subfolder of the META-INF directory, which will be read by default. In
>   that case, all you need to do is:
>
> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
> ```

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention that this has to be run on a build server that also does not have access to the Maven repo, so any solution must be packaged with the built war file. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command for the jar that you have manually downloaded:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://yourPath/.m2/repository -DrepositoryId=yourRepositoryId -Dfile=pathJar/yourJar.jar -Dversion=yourVersion -DgroupId=yourGroupId -DartifactId=yourArtifactId
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention that this has to be run on a build server that also does not have access to the Maven repo, so any solution must be packaged with the built war file. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- Run `mvn clean package` on your project, on a machine which DOES have internet access. This will have as side effect the fact that Maven will download your dependencies and place them inside your local repository (which is in Windows Users folder, inside `.m2` folder).
- Take the entire `.m2` folder and place it on the machine which does NOT have internet access.

Maven always checks local repo first, for any dependencies, so you should be fine like this. Plus, it will save you the trouble of having to install dependencies one by one, like other answers suggest.

Edit: I'd like to add that this method is useful if you have a lot of dependencies. If you have only a few - say 5 - (although unlikely), you might be better off with `install`ing them manually in your local repo (`install` is the process of placing an artifact within your local repository),

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but the work systems are locked down to the point that we can't transfer files from a system with internet access across to one without, otherwise this would be my preferred option (seeing as there's over 25 dependencies)

Comment: Don't you have to transfer those dependencies anyway?(i.e. transfer files). What's the difference if you transfer the whole repo or jars individually?

Comment: Security will allow someone (not me) to download jar files from known and trusted sites (such as the Maven repo website), which are then virus scanned and put into a secure network folder for me to access. They won't allow transfers from machines that have been hooked up to the big wide interwebz because of their paralyzing fear of viruses. I'm not saying it makes sense, but it's the corporate system I'm having to attempt to navigate to get work done.

Comment: :) I'll go cry in a corner.

Comment: I'll meet you there.